# How we can deploy an ear file in a remote jboss 8.2 wildfly server?

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, gradle, wildfly-8

Can someone please help me to deploy an ear in server.

my requirements are:

1. The ear should be deployed by by jboss-cli. Because I need to deploy the ear file in remote server.
2. It should work in all platforms like Linux, Windows etc

I want to write the code for this in a build.gradle.

so someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying via jboss-cli to a remote server is quite simple, anyway you can do this using multiple options

- building a recipe, as documented here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CLI+Recipes
- simply hacking into your favorite linux shell, as described in Adam Bien's blog here: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/deploying_from_command_line_with

Both ways work fine. I personally suggest using the second way, since most deployments aren't rocket science. :)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [Gradle Cargo plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin).